# Multi-variable functions - Chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I have been studying partial derivatives and I came across the chain rule for multi-variable functions. I have attached the definition I was given below, and I need help making sense of it.

I understand that if we have n variables and each of those variables is a function of m variables, but what happens in the case when each of those variables is NOT a function of m variables.

For example, when differentiating F(x, y, f(x, y))= 0, only z is a function of x and y and the variables x and y themselves are not.

Can someone point me in the right direction and explain to me what I am missing or not understanding? Could the definition be worded in such a way to say that each variable needs to be a function of at least 1 of the m variables?

[image]

Comment: $x$ is a function of $x$ and $y$. The same for $y$.

Comment: Oh okay. So, we are allowed to treat them in this way despite it not being explicitly stated?

Comment: Yes.  Let $g(x,y)=x$ and $h(x,y)=y$, then find $\dfrac{\partial F(g(x,y),h(x,y),f(x,y))}{\partial x}$

Comment: That makes more sense. x = g(x, y) is foreign to me, but I will need to get used to it. Thank you

Comment: $x$ is trivially a function of itself by the identity map, i.e if $\operatorname{id}:x\mapsto x$ is the identity map, then $\frac{\mathrm d~\operatorname{id}(x)}{\mathrm dx}=1$. So there is no problem.

Comment: I understand that x is a function of itself by the identity map, but the user above says to treat x as a function of x and y. This is not making sense to me

Comment: $x$ is also a function of $(x,y)$ by the projection map $\pi_1(x,y) = x$, and a function of $(x,y,z)$ by the projection map $\pi_1(x,y.z) = x$, and ...