# Multi-variable functions - composite functions

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, partial-derivative

I recently asked a question and believe a new forum is necessary. The question was in regard to partial derivatives and how we can treat the variables x, y, z in function F(x, y, z) where z = f(x, y), as functions of x and y.

Someone confirmed that we can treat x for example, as a function of x and y. However, I cannot make sense of such a function. To me, it would be something like x = x^2 + y^3 + xy.

This does not make sense to me as it is not a function of x and y and at most is a function of either x or y but not both. Also, why can we make the assumption that x is a function of x and y?

I really need clarification. Thank you in advance

Comment: $x=x^2+y^3+xy$ is not a function. It is an algebraic equation.

Comment: Then if x were to be a function of x and y, what would this look like?

Comment: But $x$ is not a function of $x$ and $y$. $x$ is only a function of itself, trivially, by the identity map. Are you interested in a plot of the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^3+xy$ ? That can be generated with a computer program.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4721346/multi-variable-functions-chain-rule

That is the question I asked before. Perhaps it will add some context

Comment: They said $g(x,y)=x$. It means the map $(x,y)\mapsto x$, which is OK.

Comment: And $x=x^2+ y^3+xy$ is not a function, this is true. But it implicitly defines a local function $y=f(x)$ which has the property that $(x,y)=(x,f(x))$ satisfies the equation.

Comment: Thank you all. That makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x$ can be a function of $y$ (and of any further variable) but not of itself.

However the equation you gave ($x = x^2 + y^3 + xy$) could be read as an *implicite function*. For instace you might transfer all variables onto a single side (then equating to zero), and then solve for $x$ by means of the "midnight formula", resulting then in some $x=g(y)$.

Wrt. your original question within $F(x,y,z)$ the $z$ could well be given as a further function $f(x,y)$, thus providing thereby an additional restriction. That one reduces your original function $F(x,y,f(x,y))$ into some other function $h(x,y)$ only.

--- rk